# displaying a nested js object on a web page

Tags: javascript, html

(more of a design question - but maybe will get a good answer on SO)

I have an object that is actually a dictionary/map (coming from a json)

The thing is that it is nested - so it is possible to have:

I want to display it on a webpage.

I thought about a tree structure (jsTree, jqTree) but it feels awkward to put on the label key:value as text.

Is there a better design pattern to display this?

key and value are strings to display, but value can be a nested (recursive) object

Example for an object:

```
{
    another_metadata: "http://www.google.com", 
    first_metadata: "plain string", 
    nested_field: Object, 
    with_https: "https://www.google.com"
}
```

Comment: Generally, I prefer to create my own parser for nested object so that I can modify it as I want and showcase the output.

Comment: I will have to write my own parser (json from the server -> tree compliant) - but the question is how to display it...

Comment: How to display what? Perhaps you can provide an example of the object and the type of display you're trying to achieve? Or at least the objectives of the display?

Comment: The question is for a general key:value structure - but I edited the question. Basically key and value are strings to display, but the value can be a recursive object

Comment: is it something like that you are looking for ? : JSON.stringify(myobject, undefined, 2);

Comment: @Hacketo - yes but it is more than that - I want to display it in a "tree" structure (with opening of a subfolder etc.) and I feel that regular tree isn't really suitable for this (because a label in not a key:value)